# How to get id from model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

In my user model I've got function that I want to return if user is following the other user.
This is the function I've added:

```
public function ifAuthorizedFollows()
{
  return $this
    ->hasMany('App\Follow', 'user_id')
    ->when(Auth::check(), function ($query) {
      return $query->where('followed_id', $this->id);
    });
    ->when(!Auth::check(), function ($query) {
      return $query->where('followed_id', null);
    });
}
```

I don't know how to get id of the user that logged user is checking the profile. If I change `$this->id` to eg. `1` it returns the follow object - thats fine, but I need to get the id of the object that is actually seeing.

This is JSON I got when changing `$this->id` to `1`:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "berde",
  (...)
  "updated_at": "2018-04-24 20:19:33",
  "pages_count": 0,
  "photos_count": 0,
  "pages": [],
  "if_authorized_follows": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "followed_id": 1,
        "followed_type": 4,
        "created_at": "2018-04-25 08:32:21",
        "updated_at": "2018-04-25 08:32:21"
    }
  ]
}
```

In my function ifAuthorizedFollow I need to get ID that appear in that json and `$this->id` is not working.

Comment: how do you call this function, can you write that statement too ?

Answer (score 0):

since it is a relation (`ifAuthorizedFollow`), you can not just return anything, it has to return a realtion.
You can however create an [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) on your model

```
[...]
public function getFollowerIdAttribute()
{
    return $this->ifAuthorizedFollow()->first()->followed_id;
}
[...]
```

this way you should be able to call the accessor on an entity

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->follower_id;
```

**Edit:**

Since you are having problems with `$this->id`, that might be an occasional context change side-effect, to be sure use the relation like this:

```
public function ifAuthorizedFollows()
{
  $id = $this->id;

  return $this
    ->hasMany('App\Follow', 'user_id')
    ->when(Auth::check(), function ($query) use($id) {
      return $query->where('followed_id', $id);
    });
    ->when(!Auth::check(), function ($query) {
      return $query->where('followed_id', null);
    });
}
```

*Note the `use ($id)` in the closure

Comment: What i need is to get id of the user (not authed one, but the one that someone is requesting) in the ifAuthorizedFollow function.

Comment: Ok sorry, seems it is working with $this->id. I thought it was not working before, i must have done something wrong.

Comment: a sample db structure would've been helpful, but I'll update my answer